# angularjs apply filter cross nested directive (filter also apply on child even it doesn't match parent)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angular, just created a angular tree with search filter... It loads nested data then fetch as a tree.

I would like the filter will also apply on child node even it doesn't match the parent, so once i use the filter, the child node will still show up even the input doesn't match the parent.

thanks for KayakDave, I correct my silly question

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/5l7sFw?p=preview

The code:

```
    app.directive('angularTree', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            treeData: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'tree.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // Some tree logic here
            // after done, pass data to directive
            scope.tree_data = scope.treeData;

            // Filter
            scope.tree_filter = function(obj) {
                // Filter here
            };
        }
    }
})
//ul inside tree
    .directive('treeBody', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                tree: '=',
                treeFilter: '='
            },
            template: '<ul class="tree"><node ng-repeat="node in tree | filter:treeFilter" child-filter="treeFilter" node="node"></node></ul>'
        }
    })
// li & child
    .directive('node', function($compile) {
        return {
            ......
            scope: {
                node: '=',
                childFilter: '='
            },
            template: '<li>{{node.name}}</a></li>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var childTem = '<tree-body tree="node.children" tree-filter="childFilter"></tree-body>';
                // Append child
                   .......
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Your filter is being applied to both the parent and child nodes.  For instance if you filter on "N" you'll see you get the parents and some of the children.  But if you search for 'c' you get nothing because a child node is only shown if it's parent is also being shown.  This leaves the question- what do you want to have happen when a parent doesn't match the filter but a child does?

Comment: @KayakDave thanks for comment , it's my mistake on description, I would like the parent still show up once it doesn't match the filter but child does. I was keep thinking the filter only apply on parent, how stupid am I !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want parents to be visible if any of it's children are visible - one option is to add a property to each node in the tree (akin to how `ngRepeat` adds `$$hashKey`) indicating whether that node matched the test and is visible, or not.  I'll call that property `show` in the code below.

Then, when a search is done, each node's `show` property is set.  Then parents can check all their children to see if any of them are visible.

And we can rely on `$digest`'s dirty checking to ensure all the children are properly set before the parents final visibility is determined.

This recursive function returns true if any of the children have their `show` property set to true.

```
function checkChildren(nextl) {
     var i, showNode=false;
     if (nextl) {
        for (i = 0;i < nextl.length;i++) 
           showNode |= nextl[i].show | checkChildren(nextl[i].children);
     }
     return showNode;
}
```

In the filter we mark each node based on whether it matches the filter and then return true to the filter if the node matches or if any of it's children do:

```
// Filter
scope.tree_filter = function(obj) {
  var reg = new RegExp(scope.search, 'i');
  var showNode = !scope.search || reg.test(obj.name);

  obj.show = showNode;
  return (showNode | checkChildren(obj.children)) ;
};
```

[updated fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/DefepRQPI0mk5nAkHyVI?p=preview)

Comment: Great thanks for the answer. I was trying the other way: rebuild the tree data to a new array set, then load this new array to display the tree. But the rebuild way is terrible once large data comes, thought the show/hide method is currently best solution for me. Excellent! Sorry can't give you the vote atm as low reputation ><